# DataGrid row selection and printing its data

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

There are some rows in my dataGrid, when i select one of them and print it's data, only first image of database will print while i only need to print image of selected row, this snippet has error on cmd.CommandText ..., 
How can i improve it?

```
private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {                
            DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
            var dc = dv.RenderOpen();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Database\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "Select Picture from Personnels where Name= " + grdPersonnel1.SelectedItem;

            bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bmp.BeginInit();
            bmp.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream((Byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            bmp.EndInit();
            dc.DrawImage(bmp, new Rect(140, 170, 150, 150));

            dc.DrawText(new FormattedText("Name:", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection,
                 new Typeface(new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Courier New"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Bold,
                     FontStretches.Normal), 12, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black), new System.Windows.Point(700, 180));
            dc.DrawText(new FormattedText(txtName.Text, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection,
                  new Typeface(new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Courier New"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal,
                      FontStretches.Normal), 11, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black), new System.Windows.Point(550, 180));


            dc.Close();

            printDialog.PrintVisual(dv, "Print");
        }

<Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Name="PictureBox"
                   Source="{Binding Picture}" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=grdPersonnel1}" Opacity="2">
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {                
        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
        var dc = dv.RenderOpen();

         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Database\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select Picture from Database where Code=@Code";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
            cmd.Parameters["@Code"].Value = this.txtCode.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bmp.BeginInit();
            bmp.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream((Byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            bmp.EndInit();
            dc.DrawImage(bmp, new Rect(140, 170, 150, 150));

        dc.DrawText(new FormattedText("Name:", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection,
             new Typeface(new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Courier New"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Bold,
                 FontStretches.Normal), 12, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black), new System.Windows.Point(700, 180));
        dc.DrawText(new FormattedText(txtName.Text, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection,
              new Typeface(new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Courier New"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal,
                  FontStretches.Normal), 11, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black), new System.Windows.Point(550, 180));


        dc.Close();

        printDialog.PrintVisual(dv, "Print");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of control grdPersonel1 is but you should look if SelectedItem is a string... if not maybe you need SelectedValue or SelectedItem.Text (something that has the string you want to be in the Name field)

Comment: SelectedItem or SelectedValue and none of them doesn't display .Text

Answer (score 0):

I assume that grdPersonnel1 is your DataGrid, that the items is that grid is of the type Personnel and that Personnel has a Name property. If this is correct, try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select Picture from Personnels where Name= " + (grdPersonnel1.SelectedItem as Personnel).Name;
```

Comment: Yes grdPersonnel1 is my DataGrid, I used this snippet but there is error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.