# Use sql database image for DrawImage in wpf

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, uri, drawimage

About this snippet:

```
dc.DrawImage(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"E:\Images\Pic1.png", UriKind.Relative)), new System.Windows.Rect(140, 170, 150, 150));
```

If we use an image from sql database for Drawing, how can we do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10861/Storing-and-Retrieving-Images-from-SQL-Server-usin

1. Create sql table

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblImgData]
   (
       [ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
       [Name] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
       [Picture] [image] NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
   ```
2. Get image from local computer

   ```
    protected void LoadImage()
       {
           try
           {
               this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this);
               string strFn=this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
               this.pictureBox1.Image=Image.FromFile(strFn);
               FileInfo fiImage=new FileInfo(strFn);
               this.m_lImageFileLength=fiImage.Length;
               FileStream fs=new FileStream(strFn,FileMode.Open, 
                                 FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read);
               m_barrImg=new byte[Convert.ToInt32(this.m_lImageFileLength)];
               int iBytesRead = fs.Read(m_barrImg,0, 
                                Convert.ToInt32(this.m_lImageFileLength));
               fs.Close();
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
       }
   ```
3. Save image in database

   ```
   private void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           this.sqlConnection1.Open();
           if (sqlCommand1.Parameters.Count ==0 )
           {
               this.sqlCommand1.CommandText="INSERT INTO tblImgData(ID," + 
                              " Name,Picture) values(@ID,@Name,@Picture)";
               this.sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@ID", 
                                System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,4);
               this.sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@Name", 
                                System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
               this.sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@Picture", 
                                System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);
           }

           this.sqlCommand1.Parameters["@ID"].Value=this.editID.Text;
           this.sqlCommand1.Parameters["@Name"].Value=this.editName.Text;
           this.sqlCommand1.Parameters["@Picture"].Value=this.m_barrImg;

           int iresult=this.sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
           MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(iresult));
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
       finally
       {
           this.sqlConnection1.Close();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is my main link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993990/datagrid-row-selection-and-printing-its-data